# Why is my 4-function simple C++ calculator only returning the first function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I've hunted for this answer across the web and have found similar assignments given to various students, but none seemed to have my problem.  That said, I'm not able to get this simple 4-function C++ calculator to do anything EXCEPT addition.  I'm assuming it's an issue with my If/Else statements, but my code looks like every example I've seen both in my textbook and online, and my compiler is returning 0 errors or warnings.  Why I can make a switch function work perfectly but can't seem to grasp these damnable if/else functions, I don't know, but I do know that I have been struggling with this same simple program for 6 FREAKING hours (and am already an hour late turning it in, so yay for a max score of 50%)!  Someone, for the love of all that is holy, help me!!

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables 
    char function = ' ';
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    double answer = 0.0;

    //enter the input variables
    cout << "What function? (A,S,M,D): ";
    cin >> function;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter second number : ";
    cin >> num2;

    //calculate and display the answer by function chosen
    function = toupper(function);

    if (function = 'A')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        cout << "The sum is " << answer << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (function = 'S')
        {
            answer = num1 - num2;
            cout << "The difference is " << answer << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (function = 'M')
            {
                answer = num1 * num2;
                cout << "The product is " << answer << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (function = 'D')
                {
                    if (num1 > num2)
                    {
                        answer = num1 / num2;
                        cout << "The quotient is " << answer << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answer = num2 / num1;
                        cout << "The quotient is " << answer << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
                } //end if
            } //end if
        } //end if
    } //end if

    return 0;
} //end of main function
```

Comment: What does the = operator do? What does the == operator do?

Comment: I thought VS15 would give you a warning about this...

Comment: There is also an else if(condition) { // do something } conditional statement. You might want to check it out, it will make your code a bit more concise. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html

Comment: I would use the "else if" function, but my school uses computer-aided grading software, which means our answers have to be very precise to what is being taught.  As this is an Intro to C++ class, they're making us write out everything long-hand in our code so we get used to the functions themselves before we start using the shortcut methods.  It's annoying, but supposedly beneficial in the long run.

Comment: @RatHat: There is no `else if`.... it's just an ordinary `else` which happens to be followed by a statement which is not a statement block (brace-enclosed) but a single `if` statement possibly with an else of its own.  That is to say, if you write `else if`, the compiler treats it exactly like the code shown in this question with braces.

Comment: @CVHansen: `else` and `if` (`else if` is just the two next to each other, not a thing of its own) are *control-flow* statements, NOT functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt maybe I wasn't very clear in my comment. What I was trying to say is why not use else if directly?  The OP explained why.

Comment: @RatHat: You haven't understood me -- **there is no `else if`, there is only `else` followed by `if`** which he is already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement like:

```
if (function = 'A')
```

first *assigns* `'A'` to `function`, then uses that value for the conditional (which, unless you assign `'\0'`, will be true).

That's why you're only getting the first function.

You should use equality comparison rather than assignment:

```
if (function == 'A')
```

---

The prevalence of this problem is what causes otherwise sane people to suggest reversing the order of the arguments, such as with:

```
if ('A' == function)
```

and this will indeed cause a compile time error if you accidentally use `=` rather than `==`.

However, it has two problems:

- it won't work unless one of the arguments is a constant (like `'A'`) since swapping two *variables* won't allow the compiler to catch the case where you've used `=` instead of `==`; and
- it's seriously butt-ugly :-)

In my opinion, it's just best to get into the habit of checking whether you want to compare or assign, and realising that, if your comparisons seem to be misbehaving, this is one of the *first* things you should look for.

---

As an aside, you might also consider using `switch` rather than heavily nested `if` statements, since it seems a more natural fit. You can do so with something along the lines of:

```
// Init type to null so you can detect invalid functions.

char *typ = nullptr;
switch (tolower(function)) {
    // Each case will set answer and type appropriately.

    case 'a':
        answer = num1 + num2;
        typ = "sum";
        break;

    case 's':
        answer = num1 - num2;
        typ = "difference";
        break;

    case 'm':
        answer = num1 * num2;
        typ = "product";
        break;

    case 'd':
        answer = (num1 > num2) ? (num1 / num2) : (num2 / num1);
        typ = "quotient";
        break;
}

// Output message based on above switch block.

if (typ == nullptr) {
    cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "The " << typ << " is " answer << endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  I could've been done before 10pm and had my assignment in 2 hours early if I'd just realized that one stupid mistake! >_<  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @CVHansen: You could've realized that mistake in under 60 seconds if you just stepped through your code and kept an eye on the value of `function` in the debugger's "Local variables" window.  LEARN TO USE YOUR DEBUGGER.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I literally don't know how to use the debugger - we haven't covered this in our classes yet.  I'm a 1st Semester student learning basic C++; cut me some slack, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `=` with `==`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables 
    char function = ' ';
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    double answer = 0.0;

    //enter the input variables
    cout << "What function? (A,S,M,D): ";
    cin >> function;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter second number : ";
    cin >> num2;

    //calculate and display the answer by function chosen
    function = toupper(function);

    if (function == 'A')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        cout << "The sum is " << answer << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (function == 'S')
        {
            answer = num1 - num2;
            cout << "The difference is " << answer << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (function == 'M')
            {
                answer = num1 * num2;
                cout << "The product is " << answer << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (function == 'D')
                {
                    if (num1 > num2)
                    {
                        answer = num1 / num2;
                        cout << "The quotient is " << answer << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answer = num2 / num1;
                        cout << "The quotient is " << answer << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;
                } //end if
            } //end if
        } //end if
    } //end if

    return 0;
} //end of main function
```